# How to make sure at least one radio button is selected in each group, php

Tags: php, radio-button

So I am trying to put together a voting system for each entry of a thread. Each entry gets a set of radio buttons (1, 2, 3) and a submit button is at the bottom. I want people voting to make sure they select one of the three radio buttons for each entry. I thought my code was working, but it's not. The last entry if it is selected, and all others aren't, it still says that its fine. But if I don't select the last entry it is working.

```
<form action="vote.php" method="POST" name="form1"> 
<? $sql = "SELECT * FROM contest_entries WHERE contest_id='$contest_id' ORDER BY id desc";  
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR); 


while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $username=$list['username']; 
$date=$list['date_entered']; 
$pl_holder=$list['place_holder1']; 
$contest_entry_id=$list['id']; 


echo "1<input name='attending[$contest_entry_id]' type='radio' value='1'>  
2<input name='attending[$contest_entry_id]' type='radio' value='2'> 
3 <input name='attending[$contest_entry_id]' type='radio' value='3'> />";  
}?> 

<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

So then on my vote.php page after hitting submit:

```
foreach($_POST['contest_entry_id'] as $key => $something) {  
$example = $_POST['attending'][$key]; 


}  if (!isset($example))  { 
    echo "You need to vote for all entries"; 
exit(); 
}else{ 
echo "success!"; 
}
```

It works except for the last entry, if the last entry is selected and others aren't it still thinks all entries have been selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should either add hidden value with the same name before radio options or query db for id's once again to do proper iteration through all options.
2. Check if every group is different than 0/isset() inside foreach loop.

Simple solution:

```
    ...
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . attending[$contest_entry_id] . '" value="0">
    1<input type="radio" name="' . attending[$contest_entry_id] . '" value="1">  
    2<input type="radio" name="' . attending[$contest_entry_id] . '" value="2"> 
    3<input type="radio" name="' . attending[$contest_entry_id] . '" value="3">';
    ...
```

vote.php

```
    foreach ($_POST['attending'] as $id => $value) {  
        if ($value == 0) {
            echo 'You need to vote for all entries'; 
            exit; 
        }  
    }  
    echo "success!";
```

BTW: Do not assign values to variable (like $example) if you're expecting that they doesn't exist - check them directly with isset($_POST[...])

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['contest_entry_id'] as $key => $something) {  
        $example = $_POST['attending'][$key];
```

How should this work? Your radio-group has the name `attending[contest-id]` - so `$_POST['contenst_entry_id']` is not defined - is it?

Your if/else condition should be inside the `foreach`-loop brackets.

Appart from that I cannot tell you anything - please post errors or do print the `global` `$_POST` before iterating to see what is inside with `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

Comment: No it's named attending[contest_entry_id]. It has to be a different name otherwise if I select a radio button for one entry, and then try to select another radio button for a different group it only selects one, instead of allowing all entries to have their own selections.

Comment: well but this is/was not in the code-sniplet... nonetheless your if/else part should be inside the foreach loop

Comment: Ok now it looks like this:

foreach($_POST['contest_entry_id'] as $key => $something) {  
$example = $_POST['attending'][$key]; 
if (!isset($example))  { 
    echo "You need to vote for all entries"; 
exit(); 
}else{ 
echo "success!"; 

}  
}


Getting closer! Except now if only the top one entry is selected it prints out:

"Success! you need to vote for all entries"

But if I dont select the top entry and select others it prints correctly:

"you need to vote for all entries."

Comment: it is to abstract in the comment section ... please update your code on top and show me what is inside: print_r($_POST) please

Comment: why don't you use "selected=selected" for one radio button....this will make sure nothing is empty

Comment: because it is a voting system - so you will have to vote for every entry - there is no default value

Comment: When I echo the _POST['attending'] it echoes "array".

Comment: I said print_r() not echo - print_r does recursively print the array

Comment: But when I echo _POST['attending'] in the for each it displays 3 or 2 or 1 or shaver value is selected

Comment: O woops sorry.  I will let u knowa little later,I'm at work right now .  Thank you so much for replying so far I do appreciate it.