# if empty $_POST assign value in foreach loop

Tags: php

Hi want to build a program which creates surveys. I couldn' t figure out how can i assign value for a question which is unanswered. Thank you for your helps.

```
$dizi = array();
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value){
    if(empty($_POST)){
        $_POST="bos"; 
    }
    $dizi[$key] = "'".$value."'"; 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ??

Comment: I've answered to similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637523/how-to-make-sure-at-least-one-radio-button-is-selected-in-each-group-php/16638708#16638708

Comment: When user create a table at database, i don' t know how many fields are there. So i use a sql query such as INSERT INTO testcevaplar VALUES ('',$ekle) [$ekle = implode(', ', $dizi)]. If any participant of survey skip any question, values of sql query doesn' t match with fields of table. So I want to assign a value for skipped questions. I can' t check each $_POST, because I don' t know how many questions are there.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense, try this:

```
$dizi = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        $value = 'your value';
    }
    $dizi[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$_POST is an [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)
So you can access it with:

```
$bla = $_POST['bla'];
```

What you are trying to do is setting the whole array to a string which doesn't work.
You should set the new value when saving it to the $dizi array.

```
$dizi = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $newValue = $value;
    if (empty($value)) {
        $newValue = 'bos';
    }
    $dizi[$key] = $newValue;
    unset($newValue);
}
```

But this only checks if answer string is empty. So this only works if all questions are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you are trying to do is this:

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    if(empty($value))
        $_POST[$key] = 'This is an unanswered question!';
}
```

But this cannot work due to the fact that empty values aren't posted from the form.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that there is 'unanswered' question if it was not posted from the form?
You have to start from the list of the questions (which can not be forged by the user and is defined on the server-side) and check that answer for each of them exists in $_POST. If not - assign whatever you want to the skipped answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST) && (!empty($_POST))){
   foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
     if(empty($value)){
       $_POST="bos"; 
     } else{
       //put your code
     }

   }
 }
```