# When I refreshed the page the error says : " Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)"

Tags: php

Could someone help me with this problem which states that Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) and could I use too much isset in if condition?

```
if(isset($_POST['dateLoanGrantedMonth']) && isset($_POST['dateLoanGrantedDay']) && isset($_POST['dateLoanGrantedYear']) && isset($_POST['maturityMonth']) && isset($_POST['maturityDay']) && isset($_POST['maturityYear']) && isset($_POST['expiryMonth']) && isset($_POST['expiryDay']) && isset($_POST['expiryYear']) && isset($_POST['mr']) && isset($_POST['mrs']) && isset($_POST['ms']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['resident']) && isset($_POST['loanInWords']) && isset($_POST['pesos']) && isset($_POST['interest']) && isset($_POST['daysMonths']) && isset($_POST['pesosInWords']) && isset($_POST['pesos2']) && isset($_POST['penaltyInterest']) && isset($_POST['itemType']) && isset($_POST['grams']) && isset($_POST['idPresented'] && isset($_POST['contactNumber']) && isset($_POST['birthdayMonth']) && isset($_POST['birthdayDay']) && isset($_POST['birthdayYear']) && isset($_POST['male']) && isset($_POST['female']) && isset($_POST['height']) && isset($_POST['weight']) && isset($_POST['citizenship']) && isset($_POST['complexion']) && isset($_POST['principal']) && isset($_POST['interestAbsoluteAmount']) && isset($_POST['serviceChargeAmount']) && isset($_POST['netProceeds']) && isset($_POST['perAnum']) && isset($_POST['perMonth']) && isset($_POST['others']))
{
    $dateLoanGrantedMonth = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['dateLoanGrantedMonth']);
    $dateLoanGrantedDay = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['dateLoanGrantedDay']);
    $dateLoanGrantedYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['dateLoanGrantedYear']);
    $maturityMonth = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['maturityMonth']);
    $maturityDay = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['maturityDay']);
    $maturityYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['maturtyYear']);
    $expiryMonth = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['expiryMonth']);
    $expiryDay = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['expiryDay']);
    $expiryYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['expiryYear']);
    $mr = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['mr']);
    $mrs = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['mrs']);
    $ms = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['ms']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name']);
    $resident = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['resident']);
    $loanInWords = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['loanInWords']);
    $pesos = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['pesos']);
    $interest = mysqli_real_escape_string($coonnection, $_POST['interest']);
    $daysMonths = mysqli_real_escape_string($coonnection, $_POST['daysMonths']);
    $pesosInWords = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['pesosInWords']);
    $pesos2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['pesos2']);
    $penaltyInterest = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['penaltyInterest']);
    $itemType = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['itemType']);
    $grams = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['grams']);
    $idPresented = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['idPresented']);
    $contactNumber =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['contactNumber']);
    $birthdayMonth = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['birthdayMonth']);
    $birthdayDay = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['birthdayDay']);
    $birthdayYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['birthdayYear']);
    $male = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['male']);
    $female = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['female']);
    $height = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['height']);
    $weight = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['weight']);
    $citizenship = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['citizenship']);
    $complexion = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['complexion']);
    $principal = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['principal']);
    $interestAbsoluteAmount = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['interestAbsoluteAmount']);
    $serviceChargeAmount = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['serviceChargeAmount']);
    $netProceeds = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['netProceeds']);
    $perAnum = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['perAnum']);
    $perMonth = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['perMonth']);
    $others = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['others']);
```

Comment: Besides, that you can just do 1 isset call and put all variables in there, please post the **full** and **exact** error message which you get and mark the line in your code with with a comment

Comment: using 1 isset function is a good practice?

Comment: Since you have AND conditions you can do it

Comment: that long conditional can be reduced drastically, to say under 50 chars. if not less, using a `foreach`.

Comment: @Rizier123 so what efficient to use?

Comment: @soyan `if(isset($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, ...)){ /* ... */}`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll try foreach...  thanks

Comment: You're welcome. See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/26006189/ ;-) it'll get you started. There are other ways too, but that's a start. Just Google "foreach  $_POST empty php".

Comment: @Rizier123 `!empty()` is better than `isset()` ;-) it checks for both.

Comment: I even once saw a function where `mysqli_real_escape_string()` was run in a loop along with checking if any inputs were empty or not. To find it again... that's another ballgame. Finding it, would greatly reduce your code even more.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You know I sometimes get lost in all these 9457 functions and methods, which PHP has ;) (Don't ask me if I counted them all by myself)

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't... I just remember the ones I need ;-) the gravy... I can always look for later and put more on my fries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is so LONG that you can not really read it:

```
isset($_POST['idPresented']
```

is missing his `')'` so change

`isset($_POST['idPresented']` into `isset($_POST['idPresented'])`

Comment: well its all about whatever you prefer... i personally never had to make long if statements like this but what i personally prefer is use multiple lines so i can spot errors like this, im pretty sure your if statement still works if you use 3-4 enters so you can read all your code without having to scroll from left to right to see whats going on (unless you have a editor that does this for you)

Comment: by the way thanks for the help.. Yes I'm using Brackets as my text editor.