# How to get datas from a form built dynamically?

Tags: php, forms

I build different forms dynamically. I query a database where i get all the fields related to the current form ID. (i have 2 tables, one with the list of fields and one with the list of fields associated to a products).I make a join and i can get all the informations in order to build the form.

It works fine.

My question is related to the treatment of the datas sent with `$_POST`. Usually, when i know all the fields, i get the data like this :

```
$nom = htmlentities($_POST['nom']);
$prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
```

I can’t do that since i have 300 fields all with a different name.
Can i get all the post value with PHP without knowing the name field ?

Comment: you can use a `foreach` along with a `!empty() / isset()` method depending on what the form elements are.

Comment: `htmlentities()` btw, is for displaying purposes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oops `htmlentities()`has nothing to do here. Could you post an answer with `foreach`solution ? I could vote for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new variables from array keys in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916510/create-new-variables-from-array-keys-in-php)

Comment: this Q&A has what you can use https://stackoverflow.com/q/26006189/1415724

Comment: you could load the info for the form ID from the database and use that to know which $_POST variables to expect. Otherwise you could be vulnerable to over-posting attacks and so on. If you're doing any kind of server-side validation of the input (which you absolutely should be if you place any value on security at all) then you'll need to know the fields you're expecting and their types, business rules etc anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has a function for that called [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), though it is not exactly recommended to be used with user data, since a user could send any key that you're not expecting.

To achieve the same, you can also use a loop:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value; 
}
```

The security problems are the same though.

Comment: How can i improve the security ?

Comment: Extract supports using a prefix (so all variables become something like `$prefix_key`), though that might not work with your use case. A predefined list of allowed keys would help, but if you have that, you can also just loop over the keys in the list (e.g. loop over the same list that you use to generate your form).

Comment: @SébastienGicquel That's a separate question/issue altogether.